# What kind of basic class types proposed by artisan should I use in Laravel in order to make encapsulation in the profect?

Tags: laravel, class, encapsulation, laravel-artisan

I am a newbie in Laravel. So I know that technically if I want to refer to the method of some class I can do it inside some controller. According to the documentation:

> Instead of defining all of your request-handling logic as closures in your route files, you may wish to organize this behavior using "controller" classes. Controllers can group related request-handling logic into a single class. For example, a UserController class might handle all incoming requests related to users, including showing, creating, updating, and deleting users.

So as it is supposed, controllers are for route usage only. But sometimes I know the specific class will never be mentioned in routes but will be mentioned in the controller this way:

```
(new Database)->DeleteExtra($dayamount);
```

So what kind of Laravel class it is? What should I create using artisan? Is it okay if I just make a controller instead?

The class should make some manipulations with a database and should not return a view.

Comment: Laravel [eloquent models](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent) are for this purpose normally since they implement the [active record pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) and also allow interoperability with the query builder. If you don't like active record you can also create a class that implements the repository pattern. Keep in mind that Laravel is an MVC framework so a lot of the time any code that is not strictly part of MVC does not need to use Laravel specific functionality (although Laravel does offer a lot of utility out of the box as well)